# Grouping an Array of Structs with the same name that is within a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a a dictionary with a key of string and a value with an array of structs.
In the array of structs I've have structs, each with their own unique items(ex: hamburgers and hotdogs). I was wondering how you would loop through the dictionary and inside the value array, group together all the item that relate to each other and add their qty together as well. So since two structs hold the item "hamburger" how can I instead group them together and add their qty together as well. The Dates don't really matter so if one overwrites the other that is fine, the important part is the name and that their qty are added together. Also if your curious the dates are in epoch form. Thanks again!

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestStruct {
    var food: String
    var date: Double
    var qty: String
}

class Test: ObservableObject {
    let foodForYear: [String: [TestStruct]]
    
    init() {
        foodForYear = ["01" : [TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1641058794, qty: "4" ), TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794, qty: "9"),TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1652204394, qty: "10"), TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794, qty: "9")]]
    }
}
```

Goal:

```
//The Date is not important so it can change.
foodForYear = ["01": [TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794, qty: "18"), TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1641058794, qty: "14")]]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the desired output?

Comment: I edited the code to hopefully be more readable than what I had before, and also added the goal on what I'm trying to achieve. Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Comments in-line.

```
struct TestStruct {
    var food: String
    var date: Double
    var qty: String
}

let foodForYear = ["01" : [TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1641058794, qty: "4" ), TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794, qty: "9"),TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1652204394, qty: "10"), TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794, qty: "9")]]

// create dictionary to hold udated values stored by key and food
var updatedFood = [String: [String: TestStruct]]()

// loop over each key, value pair
for (key, value) in foodForYear {
    // create dictionary for this key to hold combined food items
    var foodItems = [String: TestStruct]()

    // process one item at a time
    for item in value {
        // get the food name and convert qty to Int
        let food = item.food
        let qty = Int(item.qty) ?? 0

        // assign food to current if we have seen it before
        if var current = foodItems[food] {
            // update qty and store as String
            let newQty = (Int(current.qty) ?? 0) + qty
            current.qty = String(newQty)

            // update food in foodItems dictionary
            foodItems[food] = current
        } else {
            // new food, just use its name as the key
            foodItems[food] = item
        }
    }
    // update all of the foods for this key
    updatedFood[key] = foodItems
}

// convert [String: [String: TestStruct]] to [String: [TestStruct]]
let foodForYear2 = updatedFood.mapValues { Array($0.values) }

print(foodForYear2)
```

### Output:

> ["01": [main.TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1641058794.0, qty: "14"), main.TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794.0, qty: "18")]]

Comment: Did this do what you wanted?